# How to get memory usage information from Yarn to measure performance?

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce, containers, hadoop-yarn

How to know the allocated memory, utilized memory for the Yarn container from command line? Basically I want to measure the performance of the Yarn container to set optimal parameters.

Comment: What do you mean "for the YARN container"? All those properties are in your yarn-site.xml file (even if they are the defaults)

Comment: Yes. Somehow I feel the default values specified in  yarn site.xml file is not optimal and it is too high. So I think cluster is under utilised. So want to measure the actual memory utilization. So that I can tune the values in yarn site.xml to get optimal performance

Comment: All this depends on your hardware. The defaults are really too low for production sized hardware. You should consider adding JMX or Apache Ambari so you can visually monitor your cluster utilization rather than guessing at numbers